# Dreamgrow scroll box stuck in the bottom left of website?

Tags: wordpress

Dreamgrow scrollbox was working perfectly until recently, it is now stuck in the bottom lefthand corner of the website and the close button doesn't work...

Does anyone have a solution for this problem. I haven't made any page layout changes or touched the CSS recently, that was my first thought...

Nic